# How to replace next word after a specific word in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like below. Here, I want to replace just next immediate word after a particular word like, **'%(db_user)s' and '%(db_passsword)s'** but the words I can search for in the string are **--db-user and --db-passwords** becuase the above will be substituted by values.

Input:

```
 "cd scripts &&   bash setup.sh  --client-name %(client_name)s --is-db-auth-enabled %(is_db_auth_enabled)s --db-user '%(db_user)s' --db-password '%(db_password)s' "
```

Output:

```
 "cd scripts &&   bash setup.sh  --client-name %(client_name)s --is-db-auth-enabled %(is_db_auth_enabled)s --db-user '***' --db-password '****' "
```

So please help me with a function where I will provide an array of words and a string, which will replace next words to those supplied words.

Comment: @mypetlion Oh yeah

Comment: @mypetlion Actually i don't need any of them anymore :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help -

```
import re

def char_index(sentence, word_index): 
    sentence = re.split('(\s)',sentence) #Parentheses keep split characters 
    return len(''.join(sentence[:word_index*2]))

def print_secure_message(msg):
    secure_words = ['--db-user', '--db-password']
    # Removing extra white spaces within string
    msg = re.sub(' +', ' ', msg)
    cpy_msg = msg.split(" ")
    for word in secure_words:
        # Getting index of the word's first characters
        t = re.search(word, msg)
        # Getting index of the next word of the searched word's
        word_index = cpy_msg.index(word)+2;
        index= char_index(msg, word_index)
        print(t.end(), word_index, index)
        msg = msg[0:t.end() + 1] + "'****'" + msg[index - 1:]
    print(''.join(msg))
```

Comment: Is this a solution or additional info for the question?

Comment: It is solution to the question being asked.

Comment: In that case, it would be better to edit the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `insert` here. You would `.split()` your intial `string` to make it a `list`. Then you would `insert` into the position one after the `index` of the word you are searching.  After `' '.join()` the `list` back into a `string`.

```
s = "cd scripts &&   bash setup.sh  --client-name %(client_name)s --is-db-auth-enabled %(is_db_auth_enabled)s --db-user '%(db_user)s' --db-password '%(db_password)s' "

s = s.split()
a = '***'
b = '****'

s.insert((s.index('--db-user')+1), a)
s.insert((s.index('--db-password')+1), b)
s = ' '.join(s)
print(s)
# cd scripts && bash setup.sh --client-name %(client_name)s --is-db-auth-enabled %(is_db_auth_enabled)s --db-user *** '%(db_user)s' --db-password **** '%(db_password)s'
```

Comment: Yes it is working, shorter lines of code, Thanks @vash_the_stampede

Answer (score 0):

> a function where I will provide an array of words and a string, which will replace next words to those supplied words.

**Using general string processing**

The following solution leverages Python's `list.index` method which is great to find stuff in well-formatted strings, short of using regexp.

```
def replace_cmdargs(cmdargs, argmap):
   words = cmdargs.split(' ')
   for arg, value in argmap.iteritems():
      index = words.index(arg)
      argname = words[index + 1].replace('%(', '').replace(')s', '').replace("'", '').replace('"', '')
      words[index + 1] = words[index + 1] % {argname: value}
   return ' '.join(words)
```

This works by first splitting the input string into words, then for each key/value pair in argmap find the index of the key and replace the existing word at `index + 1` by the respective value.

We can use the `replace_cmdargs` function as follows

```
cmdargs = "--db-user '%(db_user)s' --db-password '%(db_password)s'"
replace_cmdargs(cmdargs, {
        '--db-user': 'MYUSER',
        '--db-password': 'MYPASS'
    })

=> "--db-user 'MYUSER' --db-password 'MYPASS'"
```

Note: This assumes the string is well-formatted, i.e. there is only one space between the key and the value to be replaced and there is always a corresponding string value.

**Leveraging Python's built-in string formatting**

Since we already have a well-formatted string with format instructions in it, we could of course also use Python's built-in string formatting 
operator, no extra function needed:

```
cmdargs % { 'db_user': 'MYUSER', 'db_password': 'MYPASS'}
=> "--db-user 'MYUSER' --db-password 'MYPASS'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on vash_the_stampede solution, here is a general solution.
It works too if there are several instances of the password which need to be replaced.

```
def clean_next_word(msg,words):

#choose your filler
filler="*****"

#isolate words in list
msg=msg.split(" ")

for word in words:

    #optional check
    if word in msg:
        
        #get all positions of key words
        indexes = []
        for i, num in enumerate(msg):  
            if num == word:  
                indexes.append(i)
        
        #replace by the filler
        for indexe in indexes:
            msg[indexe+1]=filler

return ' '.join(msg)
```

For the above exemple :

```
msg =  "cd scripts &&   bash setup.sh  --client-name %(client_name)s --is-db-auth-enabled %(is_db_auth_enabled)s --db-user '%(db_user)s' --db-password '%(db_password)s' "
words=['--db-user', '--db-password']
output=clean_next_word(msg,words)
```